# Gitlab - passing job id of parent pipeline to child pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there any way we can pass job id of parent pipeline to child pipeline as variable

```yaml
package:
  stage: package                 
  script:
    - zip -r ./service.zip

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    
  trigger:         
    include:
      - project: '<namespace>/<project>'
        ref: '<branch>'
        file: '<path to yml file>'
    strategy: depend
```

Comment: If my answer helped - please accept it

Comment: Hi gmairi, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's supported by Gitlab. You need to pass the `CI_PIPELINE_ID` built-in variable.

```
.trigger_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  strategy: depend
  trigger:
    include:
       - project: '<namespace>/<project>'
         ref: '<branch>'
         file: '<path to yml file>'
  variables:
      PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
      PARENT_JOB_ID: $CI_JOB_ID
```

You can file these and more variables in [Gitlab predefined variables documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Comment: I think you are passing pipeline id. Is it possible to pass job Id to the child pipeline?

Comment: Yes, the variable name is `CI_JOB_ID`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi andrzejwp, I was getting null while trying to read CI_JOB_ID in child artifact. My issue was to download artifacts using parent job id which is now resolved using the "needs" keyword. Thank you.

Comment: That's true, you have to use `needs` to provide artifacts to a child job. But you haven't stated that in your question.